# How to change the color of Kendo Grid elements

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to change the grid color element in Kendo UI?

[image]

I have changed the color of the text, without a problem:

```
.k-grid th.k-header,
.k-grid th.k-header .k-link
{
    color:white;
}
```

How to change the color of the arrow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow is a png so you have to create your own image and then select it as:

```
#grid .k-icon.k-i-arrow-n {
    background-image: url('path to the image');
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

You might try playing with CSS transformation and see if you can get the color that you want but that uses to be very easy if they were defined as fonts.

Comment: Thanks i saw it, is it posible to change that to FontAwesome?